# Basic chart types missing basic features

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I am trying to use Cognos Analytics 11.2.4.2 to create a report that includes a chart that meets my user's requirements.  I have tried all four visualization libraries.

My user's requirements:

- No legend
- Show data labels that include the name and value
- Dark color palette for bars
- White font for data labels
- The chart should be 7.5" wide to print full-width on a paper report.

Expected output mocked up in Excel:
[image]

Configuration options vary across Cognos visualization libraries.  Many don't allow me to adjust the font of a value label or include text in the data label, and the size for many of the bar charts can only be adjusted in pixels (not inches).  (But is a pixel on a web page always 1/96th of an inch, regardless of the actual pixel size of the display device?)

The bar chart from the 11.1 viz library seems to come closest, but still doesn't have all of the features I need.

Current output from Cognos:
[image]

Is there a way to use Cognos to present a chart with my user's requirements?
Or will I need to create a custom visualization to replace one of the most basic chart types?